# how to force google to re-index a page

Tags: seo, google-search

A website I've made has been recently hacked and Google indexed that hacked homepage and now its showing irrelevant text on search result.

The hack has been resolved but the search results haven't changed.
Is there a way to force Google to re-index my homepage?

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en - google webmaster tools - "Fetch as Google" => add to index ... DON'T MAKE THIS REQUEST MANY TIMES IN ROW - **it could slow the reindexing**!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could try resubmitting your sitemap via [Google Webmaster Central](http://www.google.com/webmasters/).

```
Site Configuration -> Sitemaps -> Submit a sitemap
```

Comment: I have added 4 sitemap generated by yost on http://www.stupidcodes.com but still the pages not indexed please suggest me to index

Answer (score 3):

If your website has been hacked and then found by Google I would recommend you to log into Google Webmaster Tools and request a reconsideration.

Write an explanation of what happend, and then submit your sitemap, keep your content updated frequently and try to get more incoming links.

Another tip, use twitter, because Google have full access to their database, it might speed up your index problem.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some SEO techniques on how you can have google reindex.  I think one thing you can try is to rename the page.  Since your page is uniquely identified by the complete url, if you change the name it causes google to reindex.  You will loose your ranking however.

Answer (score 0):

Google sees first error on the site. If there is a lot of errors within the site (end links ... etc), Google these sites virtually ignored. The content of the Google home page looks less than say on the "blog" if it exists on the site. I write from personal experience. Finally, if Google penalties site for any reason, you need to take all possible measures to restore the reputation of the site, otherwise the site and that does not exist. Frequently the first page is deleted from the index while others appear normal in the search. However, they can all be affected by the fine page directly. There are no rules.