# how to display my website metatags in SEO

Tags: html

I am having a problem ,

I updated my website to all the search engine , but when I updated the website it is showing my web hosting metatags rather than showing my metatags.

like

Domain Default page
Welcome to Parallels! If you are seeing this message, the website for is not available at this time. If you are the owner of this website, one of the following things may be occurring:
www.mcxnsecalls.com

NOTE : its showing my website domain name in the link

Pls check this link

http://www.bing.com/search?q=mcxnsecalls&go=&qs=n&sk=&form=QBLH&filt=all

after seeing it you will get idea

I want to display my titles and description 
like

MCX NSE COMMODITY TIPS

Welcome to mcxnsecalls we provide nse,mcx tips for free it and so on....
www.mcxnsecalls.com

Can anyone please say me whats the problem
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Search engine store your meta in cache to optimize there results
Unfortunately, Bing cached the meta on your web page before you added your informations.
Search engines spiders have to crawl millions of websites, so the update could takes time, depending on a lot of factors.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure why this is happening but I see that your site has not yet been indexed by google. If you have updated the meta tags recently, Bing might take a while to update the indexes.

Comment: yes i updated meta tags is this correct   
<meta name="Description" content="Stockmarket,Stocks,Commodities,Information architecture, Web Design, Web Standards." />
<meta content="mcxnsecalls.com" name="owner"> 
<title>NSE EOD data|NSE REALTIME data|EOD AND REAL TIME DATA(MCX,NCDEX)</title> 
<meta content="Quality Data vendor.Realtime (tick) and End of day(EOD) data service provider in india for NSE, BSE, MCX, NCDEX" 
name="DESCRIPTION">

Comment: The meta description is generally written as follows :
<META name="Description" content="Your descriptive sentence or two goes here."> So yeah , it seems right. I guess it would be helpfull to put more descriptive text in the description rather than having keywords such as "stockmarket, stocks, ... " etc. as this can potentially provice you with more click through traffic from the search engine results page.

Comment: Not sure how long it will take, but you can try submitting a sitemap on the search engine webmaster tools
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270294/how-to-force-google-to-re-index-a-page