# htaccess remove .php and .html from url

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem whereby google has indexed some pages with the wrong URL.

The URL they are indexing is:

```
http://www.example.com/user/emp.php
```

and HTML URL:

```
 http://www.example.com/login.html
```

I need it to redirect to:

```
http://www.example.com/user/emp
```

and HTML URL:

```
http://www.example.com/login
```

here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: The better way to do this: Let Google recrawl your site. Here is a good answer how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466360/how-to-request-google-to-re-crawl-my-website

Answer (score 4):

First check, if there exists an appropriate target ending in `.html` or `.php`, then rewrite to that URL

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: There's no need for the `NC` flag, because the patterns do not contain any case specific characters.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Thanks for input :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace it with this code in your htacess file.

```
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

And please remove .html and .php from all your links which you are calling for example.

```
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>

     To

      <a href="index">Home</a>
```

Comment: Why removing .html from the link is actually confusing to me. the rewriting happens from the server side. How come that relate to removing .html from the link?

Comment: on tag a solve problem but menu display time getting 404 error

Comment: please make sure that your file exist there and you are giving it the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the mod_rewrite module is installed, Check the output of `phpinfo();` function to confirm. I think the following `.htaccess` is fine. Place the htaccess in the root of your application.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Read [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2) on how to install mod_rewrite in php

Comment: Duplicating the non-working rules doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
  # Remove .html-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html
```