# How long does it take to show social media links in Google Knowledge Graph?

Tags: schema.org, google-knowledge-graph

I just added the Schema.org code to my website. Now how long will it take for Google Knowledge Graph to show my social links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can take weeks or months to see your Knowledge Graph in SERPs.

Comment: My website is about a year old , so how long will google to take recrawl it again ?

Comment: Depending on how well you follow the aforementioned pointers, Google can discover your website within the first four weeks of launch. Do a bang-up job, however, and your website can show up on Google in as little as four days. https://www.yokoco.com/long-take-website-show-google-bing-search-results/

Comment: you can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466360/how-to-request-google-to-re-crawl-my-website

Comment: Vikas  my business is loca but I have added the  type as organisation will it affect ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, to represent social media icons on the knowledge graph it may take a week or month after implementing it and at the same time, you need to check them once the site has been crawled.

If the social icons don't reflect on the knowledge graph the errors are in the code. In order, to check the errors you need to test your site in structured data testing tool which is available on Google for free. You can get the information from your webmaster's account.

If the tool shows zero errors and zero warnings, then definitely your social media icons are shown on the knowledge graph.